# taking input as a bot and setting it to a variable telethon

Tags: telegram, telethon

im making a bot and i have a question, this is the code:

```
@bot.on(events.CallbackQuery)
async def handler(event):
 if event.data == b"3":
     await event.respond("x", buttons=x)
 if event.data == b"7":
     await event.respond("x", buttons=x)
 if event.data == b"9": 
     await event.respond("insert x")
     @bot.on(events.NewMessage)
     async def main(event):
     messaggio =
```

and i have no idea how to set "messaggio"  to x

Answer (score 1):

```
bot.on(events.CallbackQuery)
async def handler(event):
if event.data == b"3":
    await event.respond("x, buttons=x)
if event.data == b"7":
    await event.respond("x?", buttons=x)
if event.data == b"9": 
    await event.respond("insert x")
    @bot.on(events.NewMessage(chats="x"))
    async def handler(event):
        print(str("messaggio: ") + event.text)
        messaggio = event.text
```